# Understand CreateJs

Tags: javascript, createjs

I have some problem with understanding some code

```
(function (lib_p, img, cjs) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes

// library properties:
lib_p.properties = {
  width: 364,
  height: 540,
  fps: 20,
  color: "#000000",
  manifest: [
    {src:"img/bot1_l.png", id:"bot1_l"}

  ]
};

// symbols

(lib_p.bot1_l = function() {
  this.initialize(img.bot1_l);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Bitmap();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,116,344);
```

Where can I read about this? I understand that is createJS, but I can`t figure out what all this mean - especially:

1. `(lib_p, img, cjs)`,
2. (lib_p.bot1_l = function() {
                     this.initialize(img.bot1_l);
                   }).prototype = p = new cjs.Bitmap();
                   p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,116,344);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That is how you [define arguments for a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)
2. That [instantiates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) an instance of `cjs.Rectangle`, assigns it to the variable `p`, creates a function, assigns the value of `p` to the `prototype` property of the new function, then assigns the new function to the `bot1_l` property of whatever object `lib_p` points to.